# qemu-dm processes info on Dom0 (xen server)

Tags: qemu, xen

On my Dom0, I have some guests running. For each of them, I can see a qemu process:

```
# ps -eaf | grep qemu
root      8936  3879  0 Sep13 ?        00:12:42 /usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm -d 419 -serial pty -domain-name my_pv_huest -videoram 4 -vnc 0.0.0.0:0 -vncunused -M xenpv
root     18117  3879  0 Sep18 ?        00:10:00 /usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm -d 430 -domain-name my_pvhvm_guest -videoram 4 -k en-us -vnc 0.0.0.0:0 -vncunused -vcpus 2 -vcpu_avail 0x3 -boot c -serial pty -acpi -net none -M xenfv
root     31709  3879  0 Sep18 ?        00:09:37 /usr/lib/xen/bin/qemu-dm -d 429 -domain-name my_hvm_guest -videoram 4 -k en-us -vnc 0.0.0.0:0 -vncunused -vcpus 1 -vcpu_avail 0x1 -boot c -serial pty -acpi -net nic,vlan=1,macaddr=00:16:3e:40:94:4f,model=rtl8139 -net tap,vlan=1,ifname=tap429.0,bridge=br0 -M xenfv
```

---

The first, second and third lines of output correspond to pvm, pvhvm and hvm guests, respectively.

These are my questions:

1. As far as I know , use of `qemu-dm` tool is only for the access of network and disk for HVM guests as it will not have front end drivers. Then why PVM runs as qemu-dm? Or is the process just named as qemu-dm and not related to what qemu-dm really does?
2. From where can I get more info about these running processes, at least how to understand the detailed meaning of the process information and options?

Comment: I too am wondering this, I thought qemu was only needed for HVM.

Answer (score 1):

QEMU is used for surprising things e.g. running VNC server, providing I/O when you use files for VM filesystems. 
When you don't run any guest VMs you will still have QEMU for dom0.